# How to return specific review data when specified productID is given in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to return review data for a specific productID. I have successfully returned multiple columns with the below syntax:

```
    #display productID and review text
    df1 = df[['asin', 'reviewText']]
```

I have successfully returned all data for a given productID with below syntax:

```
    #display all orders with specific ASIN
    filtered_data = df[df["asin"]== '0739079891']
```

Is it possible to use the = to specify a given asin(productID) and also display the reviewText associated with that specific productID?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for filter by mask and also by columns names in list:

```
filtered_data = df.loc[df["asin"]== '0739079891', ['asin', 'reviewText']]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! This was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the above answer, I also use df.query very frequently. Syntax:

```
dfSub = df.query('asin=="0739079891"')[['asin', 'reviewText']]
```